# Split a long string into full sentences in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have string data I've pulled from the internet.  I want to parse it into it's full sentences.

So, for example:

```
library(RXKCD)
library(stringr)

searchXKCD("health")

getXKCD(574)
tweets <- getXKCD(574)

tweets$transcript  # This is the string I want to parse.

cols <- str_extract_all(tweets$transcript, "[A-Za-z]+") # I know how to pull out the words separated, but that's not what I want to do.

# just because
freq <- table(cols)

plot(freq)
```

Ultimately, I want to end up with:

[image]

Comment: Try with `str_wrap` with `width`

Comment: Can you show some reproducible data?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `RXKCD`, can you just post (using `dput`) the results that you get out of `getXKCD`? This question is really only about strings, so reducing the number of (esoteric/rare yet admittedly cool) packages is helpful to getting exposure and an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann the reproducible data is the data from the image I pulled.

Comment: @r2evans actually, it 's relevant.  I am using data from an XKCD image in my project but the question is about the strings.

Comment: How is this **reproducible** for us?

Comment: Jen, your question is *"Split a long string into full sentences"*, which to me means that you have long strings and want to split them by some criteria. Unless I'm mistaken, it doesn't matter if it's from xkcd or dilbert or doonesbury or project gutenberg, you have long strings and you want to split them.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann because if you run that code you get the data in the tweets object.  You do have to install RXKCD and I didn't include the line to install it, figuring it was implied.  But the data is produced in line 7.

Comment: @r2evans, I guess I could've just used dput() on tweets, true.  But, this is easier and more fun.

Comment: I believe that attitude to be a little cavalier with others' time. While it's completely my choice to read and/or attempt to answer a question, I find it a little disheartening that you willingly think it's fun to make things a little harder for us to try to solve your problem. To me, "more fun" would have been including that context (I do enjoy XKCD) but still providing easy access to the necessary data. Understand that our time is not free, though we do not charge for it.

Comment: @r2evans I suppose I didn't think it was cavalier.  I thought it was relevant AND I intended to make it easier and more succinct for everyone.  That's not cavalier.  Perhaps I am wrong, sure.  The "more fun" was directed at it being fun to download a comic.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand your intent and desire to keep things from being boring, dry, unexciting, etc. I appreciate it, even. All I'm saying is that by doing so, you are either (a) making it less likely that somebody will help, when they run up against a "this is just a little too hard for now"; or (b) making some parts unnecessarily harder on us. I don't think you were intentionally cavalier, I'm just providing a different perspective: unintended consequences. Don't diminish your fun, Jen, but SO questions are not always about the journey (imho).

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, I appreciate your perspective on it!  Keeps me (an old dog) learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a case of parsing the string and cutting it into the appropriate segments:

```r
strsplit(strsplit(tweets$transcript, "(\\}\\})|(\\{\\{)")[[1]][3], "\n")[[1]][-1]
#> [1] "SKEEVE37: Oh God I ate pork yesterday before I knew about swine flu!"                                                                 
#> [2] "HANNELOREEC: Without duct tape I can't seal the door to keep out swine flu but I can't get duct tape without going outside! Help!"    
#> [3] "PAULYSHOREFAN: How long until the swine flu reaches me here in Madagascar?"                                                           
#> [4] "CRACKMONKEY74: Swine flu is God's punishment for the ACLU and lesbians and 9"                                                         
#> [5] "11 and nanobots!"                                                                                                                     
#> [6] "TWILIGHT7531: I fell down the stairs and there was a crack and a jagged white thing is sticking out of my arm guys is this swine flu?"
#> [7] "WIGU: @UNTOWARD: No, that sounds like syphilis, not swine flu. What did you say you did with a pig?"                                  
#> [8] "2011SENIORSRULE: My Dad said flu vaccines are linked to autism, so to be safe from swine flu I'm trying to lick an autistic kid."
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan!  I will see if I can further parse it from there.  I am not well-versed in string parsing, in general, so this helped me advance a little in my understanding (by looking at the pieces).

Comment: I ended up doing this:  
cols <- gsub("[A-Z]{5,}|[[:digit:]]+{4,}","",gsub("[\r\n]", "",gsub(".*:","",strsplit(tweets$transcript, "\\:")[[1]][-1][-9])))

But I needed your help to get here, so thanks, again!